# Ошибка рендеринга

Tags: android, android-layout

**Проблема:** установил новую *Android Studio 1.5*, при создании обычной `Blank Activity` *main_activity.xml* не рендерится. Вот код макета:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.dugin_rostislav.mynewapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Сначала во вкладке *Design* ничего не отображалось и была ошибка (выставил API 15, Android 4.0.3):

> The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
>   PorterDuff Color Filters are not supported.

После компиляции приложения (на телефоне работает без проблем) снова ничего нет и ошибки:

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom
>   views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE 
>   Exception Details java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use
>   a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.   at
>   android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:182)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:176)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)

**Вопрос:** почему появляются ошибки, как сделать, чтобы при стандартной генерации проекта все создавалось без ошибок и как сделать, чтобы макет графически отображался в *Design*?

Comment: Превью в студии плохое-плохое. Просто не пробуйте с ним работать и проблем не будет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а как мне макет делать? Предварительный просмотр мне нужен. Не запускать же программу по 20 раз, чтобы подобрать нужный `dp`!)

Comment: Ну, лично я так и делаю - сменил dp - перезапустил. Это проще, чем пытаться заставить предпросмоторщик работать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мне кажется, или у Вас стоит не пентиум с 3гб оперативки DDR2, как у меня?)

Comment: Ну, у меня чуть посильнее, да... Но всё же предпросмоторщик глючный. Это вам тут каждый скажет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, но все равно без него тяжелее, намного... Буду надеятся, что кто-то поможет.